Can I make new bone parent relationships without breaking my existing animations?
I have a bit of an issue regarding making an aim offset in my true FPS.
I imported my skeleton with a whole bunch of animations into Unreal no trouble, but when it came to getting the aim offset set up, I realized that when I rotated the spine (or any of the bones that are parents to the hands and feet) they would stay where they are and get horribly mangled, and manually moving them back into place would be a nightmare.
I figured it was a problem with the IK bones not being parented to the mesh's spine, so I did that in blender and fixed it, but now in every single one of my animations the hands are in the wrong position due to now being influenced by the spine it is the child of. I have made a TON of animations and it would be an absolute nightmare to fix them all up, but that is what I am now facing.
This is before parenting (how it should look):

This is what it looks like AFTER parenting IK bones to Spine:

My question is this: Is there SOME way to make it so parenting doesn't affect the animations I have already made? I kind of need the IK bones to move with the spine. The only options I see are keep offset and connected when I do the parenting.
Thank you for your time.
EDIT: Added Photos for clarity.

Hey, can you update your question with a few screenshots of your issue, these kinds of problems are harder to solve if we can only understand it by reading a description. Often in cases like rigging it's useful to share your blend file as well. Instructions for sharing.

Hi Jakemoyo, thanks for responding! I've edited the post and added photos for clarity.
